# Logic question involving Rules of inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

As a homework I got the following question.

> Say whether or not the following argument is a valid argument. Explain your answer.
>
> (a) Successful candidates for this job must have either a Bachelor's degree or five years of work experience
>
> (b) Alvin has a Master’s degree
>
> (c)Alvin got the job
>
> ---
>
> (d) ∴ Johnny does not have five years of work experience

The way I tried to approach this was using the inference logic rules, I translated the previous statement as follows:

$p \implies (q \lor r)$

$q$

$p$

And combined the first and third line Using the Modus Ponens rule to reduce it as follows

$(q \lor r) \land q $ or in the notation I used earlier

$(q \lor r)$

$q$

I'm now asking myself if this is a valid thing to do?

Comment: First, you should state whether you think the argument is valid. You should give an informal but precise explanation for why you hold this opinion. You should then be more precise in exactly how you're translating each piece of the English argument into formal logic (what exactly do $q$ and $p$ mean?).

Comment: Ask yourself this question:  Is it possible to construct a world in which (a) through (c) are true but (d) is not true?  Why or why not?  (If your answer is no, you can support this answer with a concrete example, but if your answer is yes, you should support it with reasoning.)  If you can construct such a world, then the inference isn't valid.  If you can't, then it is valid.

Comment: Intuitively, the conclusion is about Johnny that does not occur at all into the premises: thus, the conclusion can be either true or false, irrespective of the truth-value of the premises.